# accessing hash elements using php

Tags: php, arrays, hash

I have a hash array in the form

```
[{"sector":"Consumer, Cyclical","ticker":"NWY","entity":"New York & Co","New_York_&_Co":[{"count":1,"entity":"New York"}],"type":"SCap"}]
```

I am trying to list the values corresponding to key value "entity" of all occurences.
I did use json_decode,

```
$testJson = json_decode('[{"sector":"Consumer, Cyclical","ticker":"NWY","entity":"New York & Co","New_York_&_Co":[{"count":1,"entity":"New York"}],"type":"SCap"}]');
```

When I tried `echo var_dump($testJson[0]);
it shows the output in form

```
array
  0 => 
  object(stdClass)[438]
  public 'sector' => string 'Consumer, Cyclical' (length=18)
  public 'ticker' => string 'NWY' (length=3)
  public 'entity' => string 'New York & Co' (length=13)
  public 'New_York_&_Co' => 
    array
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[439]
          ...
  public 'type' => string 'SCap' (length=4)
```

but `echo var_dump($testJson[0]->entity)`  or echo var_dump($testJson[0]->sector) gives me error.. "Trying to get property of non-object" ..What Could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Is the code you tested missing single quotes around the string value, as in the sample? (It should be: `json_decode('[{"sector":"Consumer,...`.) If the posted code isn't representative, please update it.

Comment: Please check the output of var_dump that I specified in the question part.. it shows another array, right? could that be the isue?? array 0=>

Comment: the input "[{"sector":"Consumer, Cyclical","ticker":"NWY","entity":"New York & Co","New_York_&_Co":[{"count":1,"entity":"New York"}],"type":"SCap"}]" is coming from an array, that should be string right?

Comment: My point is the sample code wasn't legal PHP. Since it wasn't representative of the code you ran, it also won't have the same issues. (Consider picking a [meaningful username](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) so [at-replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) will work.)

Answer (score 1):

```
$testJSon= json_decode('[{"sector":"Consumer, Cyclical","ticker":"NWY","entity":"New York & Co","New_York_&_Co":[{"count":1,"entity":"New York"}],"type":"SCap"}]');
//var_dump($testJSon);
echo $testJSon['0']->sector; // will output `Consumer, Cyclical`
echo $testJSon[0]->{'sector'}; // will also output same
```

and you can convert it in array and get the values like:

```
$testJSon= json_decode('[{"sector":"Consumer, Cyclical","ticker":"NWY","entity":"New York & Co","New_York_&_Co":[{"count":1,"entity":"New York"}],"type":"SCap"}]',true);
echo $testJSon[0]['entity']; // will return "New York & Co"
```

Comment: no it doesnt...it gives me the error "Trying to get property of non-object" ... The above solution is the one for javascript...that wrks fine... it doesnt wrk this way in php

Comment: y is zero inserted inside single quotes?

Comment: @user1371896 its working fine in php for me in both ways, did you pasted the real json you are using ?

Comment: What could be causin the error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: I've pasted the code working here (http://codepad.viper-7.com/PRITQo), you can compare the code and output.